# Can we share a static field across Application domains?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, clr

Consider a process, in which multiple Application domains are created. Can we share a single static field across these Application domains or can we pass this static field across these application domains? How does CLR handle this?

Answer (score 1):

C++/CLI can do this, using [`__declspec(process)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xs15886w.aspx) vs [`__declspec(appdomain)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6ykz7kt.aspx).  I'm not sure exactly how it records that in the metadata or whether that's an attribute to do that in other languages.